# C# Active Directory: Get home directory path of all users

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Is it possible to get all users home path from active directory when we didn't know domain name? (Maybe we can get if from somewhere)

Comment: Do you mean the OneDrive root path?

Comment: @Kvble no i mean this: e.g `C:\Users\MTS`

Comment: That can't be known from AD. You'd have to connect to each computer. Why do you want to know that? Are you sure you don't just want the [`homeDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-homedirectory) attribute in AD?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Okey, I was wrong, yes i need homeDirectory attribute, but then i want to for e.g. list all folders from this path. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Just view that as a totally separate question: [How to list folders in UNC path](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+list+folders+in+UNC+path)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a local directory using active directory and MS Graph, to do this you should use OneDrive, or an alternative is to make a shared directory in a LAN without active directory